# Best way to merge two dataframes based on the key column

Tags: r

A key column between two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), quant = c(23,4,34,52,22))
df2 <- data.frame(tshape = c(43,3,5,1,6), id = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

I used all options

```
dfall <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "id", all = TRUE)
dfall <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "id", all.y = TRUE)
dfall <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
dfall2 <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

but anyone give the result I try to extract:

```
id  quant tshape 
1    23     43
2     4      3
3    34      5
4    52      1
5    22      6
```

Comment: `dfall <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "id", all = TRUE)` Works for me.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken but I think you may be getting confused by the index/rownames. That is not an actual column but just part of the printing of a data frame. If you do not want to see those numbers `print(dfall, row.names=F)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following appears to give me the correct output:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), quant = c(23,4,34,52,22))
df2 <- data.frame(tshape = c(43,3,5,1,6), id = c(1,2,3,4,5))
dfall <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id")
```

This gives output

```
>print(dfall, row.names=F)

id quant tshape
1    23     43
2     4      3
3    34      5
4    52      1
5    22      6
```